# CodeIgniter use a global session variable from contructor

Tags: php, codeigniter, undefined

I need to use a session information in various functions of my controller, but I can't initialize it in the constructor, because I get an error. `Message: Undefined property: Soporte::$session`

```
class Soporte extends MY_Controller {

  function __construct(){
      parent::__construct( $module, $functionality );
  }

  public function actualizarSolicitud( $id_solicitud ){

     $session_data = $this->session->userdata('session_user');
     $user = $session_data['usuario'];
     ...
  }

  public function adminHistorico(){     

     $session_data = $this->session->userdata('session_user');
     $user     = $session_data['usuario'];        
     $config   = array();
     ...
  }

  ...

}
```

There's a way to initialize a global variable $user?

Comment: Where do you save the user to the session?

Comment: possible duplicate of [PHP: "Notice: Undefined variable" and "Notice: Undefined index"](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4261133/php-notice-undefined-variable-and-notice-undefined-index)

Comment: Yan Berk, I save it in MY_Controller Class. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Try like below, model is quite complicated so I'm not providing it's code, but you should get the point. Any questions let me know.

```
/**
 * This class is used for performing all read/write session operations
 * Native php session is utilized (MY_Session library)
 */
class SessionManager extends BaseLibrary {

    private $oUser;

    public function __construct() {
        parent::__construct();
        $this->CI->load->model('User');
    }

    public function setUser(User $oUser) {
        $this->CI->session->set_userdata('userId', $oUser->getId());
    }

    public function getUser() {
        if ($this->oUser === null) {
            $this->oUser = new User();
            if ($this->CI->session->userdata('userId')) {
                $this->oUser->setId($this->CI->session->userdata('userId'));
            }
        }

        return $this->oUser;
    }

    public function logout() {
        $this->CI->session->set_userdata('userId', NULL);
    }

}
```